# Making a new Package in a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9o3X.png)

I can't find the option 'Package' in the new drop-down menu on cliking on "lib" in my flutter project in Android Studio, I tried tons of solutions but nothing workd. Can somebody help?

I tried updating andriod SDK and a lot of other soulotions to solve this problem but nothing really worked out.

Comment: Please refer this for package creation :
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new package in your project by this code in terminal:

```
flutter create --template=package your_package_name
```

Comment: there is no way to have it in the new drop-down menu like normal?

Comment: This command will create package INTO EXISTING project ? If yes what the result will be done ? If no then response not resolve the question...